# Google maps marker displays in wrong location

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have some code to display a Google map for the location `(36.7771592941268,3.0516744005553846)` with a marker at this location. I create the marker with this location, the problems is that the marker shows up in the wrong place.

```js
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.7771592941268,3.0516744005553846);

var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    clickable: true,
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
```

To demonstrate, when I put my coordinates `(36.7771592941268, 3.0516744005553846)` into Google maps directly, I see the same problem.  The green arrow (in the link below) is where I want my marker to appear in my code, but the marker always ends up where the red balloon is ([see here](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&authuser=0&q=36.800866193412595,2.9163337101562092&aq=&vps=1&sll=36.26577,-92.54324&sspn=0.698678,1.41861&vpsrc=0&t=h&g=36.26577%20-92.54324&ie=UTF8)).

Answer (score 0):

your coordinates are obviously wrong, google shows the correct location for the given coordinates.

Comment: You're right, it does (goes without saying) but for some reason the marker doesn't show up on the coordinates I give it in my code.  I'll give you another coordinate which is more explicit: 36.800897435868364,2.9159228894530997 .  If you bring this up in google maps directly, the green arrow is this coordinate, but the balloon shows up at a different location.  When I put this in code, the marker shows up where the balloon is not where the green arrow is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the anchor property of marker icon ([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex)):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: {
        path: 'M0-48c-9.8 0-17.7 7.8-17.7 17.4 0 15.5 17.7 30.6 17.7 30.6s17.7-15.4 17.7-30.6c0-9.6-7.9-17.4-17.7-17.4z',
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32),
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 1
    },
    clickable: true,
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
```